# what events can trigger webhook in MS Teams?

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

Hi StackOverflow community:

Hope everyone is as well as possible during this current pandemic. We're developing an AI-based system which needs to collect inputs from various sources, including MS Teams. For example, we need to be able to trigger an API call when someone clicks on a 'channel' or a 'chat', when they click on a link which takes them outside of MS Teams (for example, they click on a weblink which takes them to a website), when they post in a chat/channel and so on.

Given that this program will be used by many non-technical users, we don't want the user to have to initiate the API call - it has to be done automatically.

I was hoping please that some people would be able to let me know which actions can/can not trigger API calls and outgoing webhooks? And the best way of automatically triggering the API calls when these events occur?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Josh

Comment: Please help me understand your exact scenario here? What kind of API do you want to trigger?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT, I believe the OP would like to capture User Interaction in MS Teams and log these on an external webserver.

Comment: Hi @ikel - that's correct - we would want to automatically log any action a user takes (including clicks, messages and so on) on an external webserver. Thanks for helping to clarify!

Comment: Are you using a Bot? If so, you could get the details of user action using [Bot events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet).